# How would I get a cron job to run every 30 minutes?

Tags: linux, macos, cron

I'm looking to add a `crontab` entry to execute a script every 30 minutes, on the hour and 30 minutes past the hour or something close. I have the following, but it doesn't seem to run on 0.

```
*/30 * * * *
```

What string do I need to use?

The cron is running on OSX.

Comment: Have you succeeded in getting your crontab to work?  Your problem may not be the crontab, but getting it to be used.

Comment: It's running 2 other scripts, one every minute.

Comment: I'm waiting to see if one of the answers below works, just have to wait till the next 30 minutes is up...in 3 minutes.

Comment: ... Couldn't you just change 0,30 to 0,5 ? If 0,5 works, why wouldn't 0,30?

Comment: You never told us if it worked on the hour!

Comment: @Gortok, I guess you're right, but it's always good to test in the real situation as well :)

Answer (score 546, accepted):

Do:

```
0,30 * * * * your_command
```

Comment: Works great! In CentOS crontab, I had to do something like `0,30 * * * * root your_command` where root would be the user I'm using.

Comment: @prograhammer - Was this line part of a root's crontab or some other user's crontab?

Comment: @MuhamedHuseinbašić good question, since there are 2 different crontabs (the global one and then a user's). I'll have to check and see...

Answer (score 196):

crontab does not understand "intervals", it only understands "schedule"

valid hours: 0-23 -- valid minutes: 0-59

**example #1**

`30 * * * * your_command`

this means "run when the minute of each hour **is 30**" (would run at: 1:30, 2:30, 3:30, etc)

**example #2**

`*/30 * * * * your_command`

this means "run when the minute of each hour is **evenly divisible by 30**" (would run at: 1:30, 2:00, 2:30, 3:00, etc)

**example #3**

`0,30 * * * * your_command`

this means "run when the minute of each hour **is 0 or 30**" (would run at: 1:30, 2:00, 2:30, 3:00, etc)

*it's another way to accomplish the same results as example #2*

**example #4**

`19 * * * * your_command`

this means "run when the minute of each hour **is 19**" (would run at: 1:19, 2:19, 3:19, etc)

**example #5**

`*/19 * * * * your_command`

this means "run when the minute of each hour **is zero or evenly divisible by 19**" (would run at: 1:19, 1:38, 1:57, 2:00, 2:19, 2:38, 2:57, 3:00 etc)
[image: crontest conducted over one hour]

*note: several refinements have been made to this post by various users including the author*

Answer (score 78):

Try this:

```
0,30 * * * * your command goes here
```

According to the official Mac OS X [crontab(5) manpage](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/crontab.5.html), the `/` syntax is supported.  Thus, to figure out why it wasn't working for you, you'll need to look at the logs for cron.  In those logs, you *should* find a clear failure message.

Note:  Mac OS X appears to use Vixie Cron, the same as Linux and the BSDs.

Comment: I've always used */30 with success but I don't recall an application of mine where it was too critical if it only ran once an hour so I don't think I've ever checked.

Comment: @Adam Hawes: I've also used */xx with success in the past, but on Linux and other UNIXes.  I've not personally tried Mac OSX.  The original question didn't say which OS.  Some older UNIXes don't support */xx

Answer (score 10):

If your cron job is running on Mac OS X only, you may want to use launchd instead.

From [Scheduling Timed Jobs (official Apple docs)](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/ScheduledJobs.html):

> Note: Although it is still supported, cron is not a recommended solution. It has been deprecated in favor of launchd.

You can find additional information (such as the [launchd Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchd)) with a simple web search.

Answer (score 9):

You can use both of '**,**' **OR** divide '**/**' symbols. 
But, '**/**' is better. 
Suppose the case of 'every 5 minutes'. If you use '**,**', you have to write the cron job as following:

```
0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,....    *      *     *   * your_command
```

It means run your_command in every hour in all of defined minutes: 0,5,10,...

However, if you use '/', you can write the following simple and short job:

```
*/5  *  *  *  *  your_command
```

It means run your_command in the  minutes that are dividable by 5 or in the simpler words, '0,5,10,...'

So, dividable symbol '/' is the best choice always;

Answer (score 5):

You mention you are using OS X- I have used [cronnix](http://roaringapps.com/app/cronnix) in the past. It's not as geeky as editing it yourself, but it helped me learn what the columns are in a jiffy. Just a thought.

Comment: This could be helpful otherwise as well.