# Run my python3 program on remote Ubuntu server every 30 min

Tags: python, ubuntu, digital-ocean

I have correct python3 program looking like *.py.
I have Digital Ocean(DO) droplet with Ubuntu 14.04.
My program post message to my twitter account.
I just copy my *.py in some directory on DO droplet and run it with ssh and all works fine.
But I need to post message(rum my program) automatically every 15-30 min for example.

Iam newbie with this all. 
What should i do? Step-by-step please!

Comment: Have you considered using cron? 
http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference/

Comment: @HiteshDharmadasani
A. ) Repeat pattern like /2 for every 2 minutes or /10 for every 10 minutes is not supported by all operating systems. If you try to use it and crontab complains it is probably not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cron is probably the way to go - it's built for this task. See this [DigitalOcean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-cron-to-automate-tasks-on-a-vps) for details.

[This StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/584776/353839) explicitly states what to put in for a 30 minute repeat interval.

If you don't want to use cron for some reason, you could do something like:

```
import time

# Repeat forever
while True:
    post_to_twitter() # Call your function
    # Sleep for 60 seconds / minute * 30 minutes
    time.sleep(60 * 30)
```

Comment: Thanks! Can i use other python program on this droplet while my first program «repeat forever»? What about server resources? Cron or «repeat forever» uses less?

Comment: Yes, you may run other programs - see [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-command-line-run-in-background/). As for resources, I imagine cron will use less. The Python program is sleeping and not doing much, though.

Answer (score 0):

First install and enable `fcron`. Then, `sudo -s` into root and run `fcrontab -e`. In the editor, enter `*/30 * * * /path/to/script.py` and save the file. Change 30 to 15 if every 15 minutes is what you're after.