# Automate Selenium scripts to run every 15 mins?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

i have written a script using Selenium Webdriver. Just wanted to know if there is a way to make this script run every 15mins?

Like if i schedule it for 1 hour, Scripts should run every 15 mins and at the end of 1 hour it should post the results to an excel sheet. Can someone pls help me on this?

Comment: Are you aware of jenkins?
if yes, it can make your job much easier by using cron, else, you can write custom code for this(I can help in this)

Comment: Thanks Anil. No, Im not aware of Jenkins. Can you help me in this custom code ?

Comment: Anil, is it ok if i share you the script that i have written.. so that u can help me with the custom code?

Comment: sure!!! Please send the script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are a beginner, so I am trying to provide you a very easy solution, might be not very much efficient.

```
static Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                // Your database code here
                  if(i==4){
                      timer.cancel();
                      timer.purge();
                  }
                  try {
                    execute();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                  i++;

              }
            }, 0, 1*1000);
```

In Code, 1*1000 denotes like, after how many seconds , you want to execute your code.
execute() -- will have your code to be run
i :- number of times, you want to repeat your test
in your case
i=4
timeRate should be :- 15*60*1000

Answer (score 0):

Crontab is the best  thing to do this job. Write a selenium script and run for every 15 min using crontab. Refer this link to run it for every 15 min.

[How would I get a cron job to run every 30 minutes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584770/how-would-i-get-a-cron-job-to-run-every-30-minutes?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins or Hudson would be the ideal candidates to host this.